# Parsing output of command

Tags: java, string

I got this method to check service states:

```
private int checkService(String SERVICE_NAME) {
String[] script = {"cmd.exe", "/c", "sc", "query", SERVICE_NAME, "|", "find", "/C", "\"RUNNING\""};
int s = 0;
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(script);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        String starting = "START_PENDING";
        String stopping = "STOP_PENDING";
        while (line != null) {
            if (line.toLowerCase().contains(starting.toLowerCase())) {
                s = 3;
            }
            if (line.toLowerCase().contains(stopping.toLowerCase())) {
                s = 2;
            }
            if (line.equals("0")) {
                s = 0;
            }
            if (!line.equals("0") ) {
                s = 1;
            }
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e1) {
        System.out.println(e1);
    }
    return s;
}
```

I want to make this line work:

```
if (line.toLowerCase().contains(starting.toLowerCase()))
```

but i cannot find a string in "line" because "line" is not a string... I want to catch this:

```
SERVICE_NAME: OracleServiceORCL 
    TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS  
    STATE              : 2  START_PENDING 
                            (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
    CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
    WAIT_HINT          : 0x7d0
    PID                : 4144
    FLAGS              :
```

3rd line START_PENDING is what im looking for, depending on the service state the actions should be different. I have tried converting the bufferedReader with apache commons.io but it just prints white spaces... How can i properly change this code so that this info becomes a string?

Comment: What do you mean 'because "line" is not a string'?  You declared line as a `String`, what else would it be?

Comment: @azurefrog yea indeed it is string but I cannot output it in a system.Out.Print because of the reader. Line is 0 or 1 depending if the service started or not but I also want to check the other states... If I do an system. Out of the line before the while loop ends, the output will be 0 if the service is stopped

Comment: I think your actual problem is the `exec`.  Do you mean to pipe the output of `cmd.exe` into `find`?  That won't work (like that).  `exec` (unlike `system` but just like `exec…` in C) does not spawn a shell.  Also I think you might be mixing POSIX and Windows.  Did you try simply printing all the output of your subprocess and check it visually?  Finally, the `p.waitFor()` should be removed.  All it will do is fill up some I/O buffers somewhere.  Just start reading the stream right away.  It will block if no output is ready.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad: `cmd.exe` is a shell, right?  However, your `if`-cascade is suspect.  Shouldn't you `return` the value you assign to `s`?  Your code will most likely always return 1 except if the last line of output is exactly the string `"0"`.

Comment: Or put differently: What *are* you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @5gon12eder notice the 3rd line saying START_PENDING, those lines are caught AFTER the CMD command was sent. I want to catch the 3rd line of that service state to do different actions. For example: if i check the service state every 2 seconds, if the 3rd line is readed as: START_PENDING set label background color to yellow for example. The thing is that once you send a cmd it starts running and you get 2 results, if it failed or if it worked, but after it got executed i want to check the state of the service, if its either in state START_PENDING or STARTED.

Comment: So why do you have those `line.equals("0")` checks then?  Simply return one value if you match a line against `"START_PENDING"`, another value for `"STOP_PENDING"` and an error if none is matched.

Comment: @5gon12eder Its a CMD thing, if you check the state of the service and it is not running it returns a 0 string.

Comment: Fair enough, but your logic is still wrong.  Just step through the conditionals by hand and see what will be returned.

Comment: @5gon12eder the only if's working are these: line.equals("0") and the other one !line.equals("0"). I cant understand the !line.equals . While the program is not running if you check its state it returns a "0" string. But if the program is running it doesnt return "1", it returns an value I cannot parse as a variable to print, its like if the program is running and everything is OK it throws something that is not an "1". Kinda like an object, i coudnt parse neither integer or string from that line. Seems like "0" is like universal, and find yourself to deal with the other states... kinda creepy

Comment: What do you mean by “working”?  Just add print statements inside the `if`s and see when they are entered (they are, I did it, mocking your external command).  And add a print for `line` in each iteration of the loop to see what you are parsing as I have suggested before.  BTW: We are kindly reminded that this discussion is inappropriate for a comments section.  Should I click the “move this discussion to chat” link?  I have never tried this before so it might kill us.

Comment: @5gon12eder sure, woudnt like to go against forum rules xD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61619/discussion-between-5gon12eder-and-alpha2k).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working, this is the right method for my needs:

```
private int checkService(String service) {
    int s = 0;
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sc query " + service);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            if (line.trim().startsWith("STATE")) {
                switch (line.trim().substring(line.trim().indexOf(":") + 1,     line.trim().indexOf(":") + 4).trim()) {
                    case "1":
                        s = 0;
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        s = 3;
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        s = 2;
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        s = 1;
                        break;
                }
            }
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        System.out.println(e1);
    }
    return s;
}
```